# Linq to SQL Queries determined at runtime

Tags: linq-to-sql

The number of query conditions is determined by user selections at runtime, ie

```
var results= from r in db.Table 
             where condition A && condition B && ... condition XX...
```

Is the best way to handle this to build a string variable and append to it or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the extension methods.  You can use these to customize your query based on values of variables.  Otherwise, you can look at [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) in the VS2008 samples.

```
 var query = db.Table;
 if (lookForX)
 {
     query = query.Where( t => t.fieldX == X  );
 }
 if (lookForY)
     query = query.Where( t => t.fieldY == Y );
 }
```